# Apache Drill mash file metadata with results

Tags: sql, apache, apache-drill, nosql

My present query on Apache Drill is as follows -

```
select 
 CAST(columns[0] AS Integer) as ID, 
 to_timestamp(SUBSTR(columns[10],1,14),'YYYYMMddHHmmss') as RecordDt
from dfs.`/data/100Krows/`
```

What I would like to do is get the modificationTime metadata for each of the .csv files in my folder as a column something like this -

```
select 
  CAST(columns[0] AS Integer) as ID, 
  to_timestamp(SUBSTR(columns[10],1,14),'YYYYMMddHHmmss') as RecordDt,
  modificationTime as versionStartTime
from dfs.`/data/100Krows/`
```

The modificationTime metadata can be found when I run the following

```
 SHOW FILES in dfs.data
```

Is there a way to achieve this in its current version 1.1 or 1.0?

**UPDATE 1**

What I am truly looking for is the file metadata included in the result set of select statement against individual files

if my directory structure is as follows -

```
dir0
 dir1
  samefilename.csv    -- Modified Date - 10/01/2013
    *******DATA******
    Col0,Col1,Col2
    Val1-2013,Val2-2013,Val3-2014
    *******DATA******
 dir2
   samefilename.csv    -- Modified Date - 10/01/2014
    *******DATA******
     Col0,Col1,Col2
     Val1-2014,Val2-2014,Val3-2014
    *******DATA******
```

Kind of query I want to write -

```
select 
  name             as filename,  
  modificationTime as versionStartTime,
 Col0,
 Col2,
 Col3
from dfs.`/dir0/`
```

Expected Result -

```
 Columns[0]         Columns[1]   Columns[2]        .....
 samefileName.csv   10/01/2013   Val1-2013         .....
 samefileName.csv   10/01/2014   Val1-2014         .....
```

Comment: See issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dakuji,

This is currently not exactly possible (as of version 1.1) but here is a proxy for it until this [Drill issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3698) that addresses your question is implemented. What I am proposing below is not the exact solution, but with some work can get you there.

Preconditions and notes:

1. Have .tbl extension registered under .psv storage configuration.
2. I do this under dfs.
3. is a placeholder for the file you name whatever you want.

Do this from the Drill's SQLLine prompt:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> use dfs;  
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> record! <file_name.tbl>  
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SHOW FILES;  
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> record!  
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select columns[9] from dfs.`<file_name.tbl>';
```

There might be some noise in some column entries, but you can further filter that out with a query.

```
> 0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> !record <file_name.tbl>
Recording stopped.
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select columns[9] from dfs.`<\path\<file_name.tbl>`;
+---------------------------+
|          EXPR$0           |
+---------------------------+
| null                      |
| null                      |
|     modificationTime      |
| null                      |
|  2013-04-26 23:44:56.0    |
|  2015-08-12 16:21:39.0    |
|  2014-04-26 10:09:33.0    |
|  2015-04-27 22:49:48.0    |
|  2013-08-24 20:16:29.0    |
|  2015-08-23 19:26:54.0    |
|  2014-10-21 16:43:38.0    |
|  2014-04-26 10:09:35.0    |
|  2014-10-21 16:43:38.0    |
|  2012-11-16 11:38:17.0    |
|  2012-11-16 11:44:27.0    |
|  2014-10-21 16:42:57.0    |
|  2014-04-26 10:09:28.0    |
|  2013-08-24 21:48:39.0    |
|  2015-08-20 22:27:34.0    |
+---------------------------+
19 rows selected (0.082 seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you this kind of gets me there if I can figure out how to use something like cursor to iterate through nested directory structure to combine file metadata with file content/data

Comment: Dakuji, we opened the JIRA issue to support the feature you are looking for. At this point this is probably the best you'll be able to get from the current (Drill 1.1) functionality.